# After isset($_GET['post_id']) === true), need to call Javascript to turn <div> visibility to hidden

Tags: php, javascript, html, visibility, hidden

Relatively new to PHP here, but here's where I'm at:

I have a simple PHP sort of email-sent validation going on, but after the page checks and confirms that the email is sent, I need to call Javascript (unless there is a better way to do this) to hide the DIV containing the email form to prevent spam.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['sent']) === true) {
    echo '<div id="formAnswer"> Thanks for the email! </div>';
  }

  if (empty($errors) === false) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($errors as $error) {
      echo '<li>', $error, '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
   }                
?>
```

I want to hopefully call a Javascript function to hide the div containing the email form based on the same IF statement that confirms the email was sent (I'd like to include setTimeout so that it's very clear to the user that the confirmation DIV appears, and they can't send another email from that page), but I can't seem to get the Javascript to execute within an echo.

Any help?

Comment: can you show your html code/form?

Comment: By hiding a form at client side, you cannot prevent spam.

Comment: This is not a subject but you can write your if statement as if(isset($_GET['sent']))

Comment: Do you load your PHP code via AJAX? If not, there will be a page refresh and you can hide the form on the server side by not adding it to the mark up.

Comment: You can't (shouldn't) mix-n-match PHP and JavaScript. You definitely shouldn't rely on JavaScript for security. Think of what you ultimately want to accomplish, and do it in only PHP. *Then* make it cool with JavaScript.

Comment: You don't really need the `=== true`, because `isset()` always returns a boolean. You can just do `if(isset($var)) {...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use document.getElementById('divid');
 elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem)
Delete the Div! to hide it :D

Comment: Very useful info, you guys are life savers. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide form with php i.e show form only if mail is not send  :

```
if(!isset($_GET['sent'])) {
   <-- form -->
}
```